# Multi-dimensional np.argmax?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I've got a 3D array of shape (n, n, g) and I'd need for every (n, n) the argmax, i.e. the result should be two index vectors (x, y) of length g each.

The intuitive solution would be:

```py
array = np.random.uniform(size=[5, 5, 1000])
np.argmax(array, axis=[0, 1])
```

However, numpy does not support multiple axes as argument.

Is there a solution to get this result anyways?

Comment: You understand the flaw with this question, right? It isn't clear at all. When you find the argmax with respect to (n, n), what is the index? In range [0, n ** 2]? Because otherwise this makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Oops, yes, you are right.

Comment: It should be two index vectors of course :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are looking to get two-dimensional (row,column) argmax indices for each flattened version of `2D` slice with the first two axes merged/combined as to speak. So, the first block would be `array[:,:,0]` and so on and we need to need find argmax with that slice being flattened and retraced back to original 2D shape. So, to solve it, we can simply reshape to merge first two axes, get argmax along the first axis which is the merged one after reshaping and retrace back the original indices with `np.unravel_index`, like so -

```
array2D = array.reshape(-1,array.shape[-1])
r,c = np.unravel_index(array2D.argmax(0),array.shape[:2])
```

Sample run -

```
In [29]: array = np.random.uniform(size=[5, 5, 1000])

In [30]: array2D = array.reshape(-1,array.shape[-1])

In [31]: r,c = np.unravel_index(array2D.argmax(0),array.shape[:2])

In [32]: len(r), len(c)
Out[32]: (1000, 1000)
```

Let's verify results for the first `2D` slice -

```
In [33]: array[:,:,0]
Out[33]: 
array([[0.81590174, 0.17919069, 0.22717883, 0.67863625, 0.97390595],
       [0.82096447, 0.05894774, 0.86379174, 0.13494354, 0.10003756],
       [0.37243189, 0.33714008, 0.21165031, 0.35910642, 0.15163255],
       [0.1376776 , 0.86866599, 0.43602004, 0.85421372, 0.77805012],
       [0.10519547, 0.7422571 , 0.35632275, 0.24168307, 0.76882613]])

In [34]: array[:,:,0].argmax() 
Out[34]: 4  # flattened index for 0.97390595 at (0,4) in the 2D slice

In [36]: r[0],c[0]
Out[36]: (0, 4)
```

Comment: I think this is the most clear and simple solution to my problem.
In order to get the maximum values, we can call array[r, c, np.arange(1000)].
Beside of that, this solution applies to other shapes, too.

Answer (score 2):

Simple using `vstack` before `argmax`

```
np.argmax(np.vstack(array),0)//5
Out[61]: array([4, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: @coldspeed we need position base on level [0,1] right ? since the first level size is 5 with out that we get [24,2] this is after we do vstack , in their real position should it be //5 , Maybe i was wrong ..

Comment: I'm not sure, let me test this. Anyway, +1

Comment: Thank you, this gets very close to my target. However, vstack-ing results in the flattened index positions, i.e. they have to be transformed back to real indices. Therefore, we have to use x = flat//5 and y = flat%5 to get (x, y) back :)

Comment: @Hoeze and Wen, I think I found the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
N, M, G = array.shape
[np.unravel_index(np.argmax(array[:, :, k]), (N, M)) for k in range(G)]
```

For simplicity, let assume n=2 and g=3:

```
import pprint
array = np.random.uniform(size=[2, 2, 3])
N, M, G = array.shape
pprint.pprint([array[:, :, k] for k in range(G)]) 

[array([[ 0.71863395,  0.86051707],
       [ 0.82812069,  0.62037209]]),
 array([[ 0.72423731,  0.59852891],
       [ 0.52208735,  0.0133947 ]]),
 array([[ 0.93927551,  0.99748664],
       [ 0.35097431,  0.48110289]])]

[np.unravel_index(np.argmax(array[:, :, k]), (N, M)) for k in range(G)] # -> [(0, 1), (0, 0), (0, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try

```
np.column_stack([np.arange(array.shape[0]), array.max(-1).argmax(1)])
```

The idea is that the first index is always monotonically increasing, so all we need is the second index.

Comment: hmm this does not seem to work. The return value has shape (5, 2)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is just to ravel and then unravel the index.  In one line:

```
np.c_[np.unravel_index(np.argmax(a.reshape(-1, a.shape[-1]), axis = 0), a.shape[:-1])]
```

EDIT: just realized this is basically @Divakar's answer stripped down to bare bones.  It is, however, valid for more than two dimensions