# np.argmax values for a multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, argmax

I have an output from a classification task with 3D array of shape `(total_n, n_samples, class)` where `total_n` is the total number of samples available, `n_samples` is number of samples each `total_n` has and `class` is the total number of classes. For example `(150,10,4)`, which explains total 150 samples, each of them with 10 items and has 4 classes.

I want to have an argmax of all these samples with a shape (150,10). I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868834/multi-dimensional-np-argmax) but could not understand much. For better explanation,  if I have an array

```
array([[[1.23322807e-01, 3.08330834e-01, 5.50771058e-01, 1.75753236e-02],
    [1.21189401e-01, 3.38278770e-01, 5.13161004e-01, 2.73708440e-02],
    [1.22608222e-01, 3.20350111e-01, 5.36035180e-01, 2.10064519e-02],
    ...,
    [1.22774929e-01, 3.17798346e-01, 5.39198518e-01, 2.02282276e-02],
    [1.22979380e-01, 3.14480424e-01, 5.43282390e-01, 1.92577895e-02],
    [9.76457149e-02, 4.26289231e-01, 3.33032995e-01, 1.43032119e-01]],

   [[1.07325114e-01, 9.32405144e-02, 7.99249947e-01, 1.84322605e-04],
    [1.03722170e-01, 8.05151463e-02, 8.15651417e-01, 1.11263049e-04],
    [9.91753787e-02, 6.70679286e-02, 8.33696961e-01, 5.97741055e-05],
    ...,
    [1.15346484e-01, 1.31869793e-01, 7.52159536e-01, 6.24184089e-04],
    [1.14123553e-01, 1.24692641e-01, 7.60672808e-01, 5.11020364e-04],
    [9.76457149e-02, 4.26289231e-01, 3.33032995e-01, 1.43032119e-01]],

   [[1.22371897e-01, 3.23767275e-01, 5.31766593e-01, 2.20942963e-02],
    [1.24506004e-01, 2.70329446e-01, 5.95326006e-01, 9.83851776e-03],
    [1.21994525e-01, 3.28812063e-01, 5.25391340e-01, 2.38020625e-02],
    ...,
    [1.24084614e-01, 2.28595763e-01, 6.42385721e-01, 4.93392395e-03],
    [1.24565214e-01, 2.60951698e-01, 6.06007338e-01, 8.47575068e-03],
    [9.76457149e-02, 4.26289231e-01, 3.33032995e-01, 1.43032119e-01]]])
```

I want an argmax for each row.
What I know, is to get an argmax for one sample as shown below but not for the whole array.

```
np.argmax(validationPredict[1][111], axis=1) #this will give me an argmax values for 10 items in 111th sample
```

which results in a list of 10 values. `[2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 1]`
I would like to have these values for 150 samples. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: What's the relation between `validationPredict[1][111]` and the (150,10,4) array?  The 111 can only index the 1st dimension. `np.argmax(..., axis=-1)` should return a (150,10) array with values in (0,1,2,3) set, identifying the max element on that size 4 dimension.

Comment: Yes, 111 represents a 1st dimension, I wanted to have it in (150,10) shape. Thank you so much, you provided me a solution for this!